# How to input an integer array without spaces or '\n'?

Tags: c

I want to input an array of integers without giving spaces.

For ex:- 032146548 ,each integer should be stored in array distinctly ,

```
i.e a[0]=0,a[1]=3,a[2]=2 and so on.
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Read it as a string and then convert each character by subtracting  `'0'`.

Comment: Do you mean arr[i]=getchar()-'0' ? @KlasLindbäck

Comment: Something like that. You probably want to use `isdigit` on each character to detect when the sequence of digits ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this if you are reading from file,

```
int i=0;
while(scanf("%1d",&a[i])==1)
{
     i++;
}
```

Use this if you know how many inputs are there,

```
for(int i=0;i<inputLength;i++)
{
    scanf("%1d",&a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to say "each digit", since it's not at all obvious how many "integers" the character sequence `032146548` represents (the common practice is "one") once you know it's supposed to be several.

The simplest way is to just read it in as a string of digits, then convert each digit to its integer counterpart by subtracting `'0'`:

```
char line[12];
unsigned int a[10];
if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
{
  const size_t digits = strlen(line) - 1;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a; ++i)
  {
    if(i < digits && isdigit((unsigned int) line[i]))
       a[i] = line[i] - '0';
    else
       a[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[16];
    int i, j, stat;
    char ch[2] ={0};

    for(i=0;i<16;++i){
        if(1!=(stat=scanf("%1d%1[^0-9]", &a[i], ch))){
            if(stat==2)
                ++i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<i;++j)
        printf("%d ", a[j]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain this:  if(1!=scanf("%1d%1[ \t\n]", &a[i], ch))  @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @madhurgarg The input character by character number by the loop. The next character in the numbers loop termination in the case of line break.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But OP asked to skip the `\n` not to stop taking input.

Comment: @Tahlil I understand that it's that it does not enter along with the new line one by one and or separated by a space.